# C program: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am currently trying to solve a task, which is quite hard for me, a beginner to C, to handle and so i came to this point where I do not know what to do anymore.

My task is to implement polynomials with several functions....
The functions should be clear when you look at the code I think.

My exact problem is that i dont get a compiler error but a Segmentation Fault. I marked where my attempts to debug lead me to. But I have absolutely no clue on what I have to change. I hope someone can help me fix my code.

So here are the three code parts:
Number one: poly.c

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "poly.h"

struct poly_t { 
  unsigned degree;
  int *coeffs; 
  }; 


  //constructor: heap
  poly_t *poly_alloc(unsigned degree){

    poly_t *heap_p;
    heap_p = malloc(sizeof(*heap_p)+(degree+1)*sizeof(int)); //or malloc(sizeof(*heap_p)*(degree+1)) furthermore not sure if degree or degree +1

  }

 //free heap 
  void poly_free(poly_t *p){
    int *coeffs = p->coeffs;
    free(coeffs);
    free(p);
  }


  void poly_set_coeff(poly_t *p, unsigned deg, int coeff){
    p->degree = deg;
    p->coeffs += deg;
    p->coeffs[deg] = coeff;

    //does not work Segmentation Fault not sure what to do
    //p->coeffs += deg;
    //*p->coeffs = coeff;
       printf("%d",*p->coeffs);
  }

//different variations
  poly_t *poly_linear(poly_t *p, int a1, int a0){
    p->degree=1;
    *p->coeffs=a1;
    p->coeffs++;
    *p->coeffs=a0;
    p->coeffs--;
  }


  poly_t *poly_quadratic(poly_t *p, int a2, int a1, int a0){
    p->degree=2;
    *p->coeffs=a2;
    p->coeffs++;
    *p->coeffs=a1;
    p->coeffs++;
    *p->coeffs=a0;
    p->coeffs-=2;
  }

//evaluate using horner
  int poly_eval(poly_t const *p, int x){
    int d = p->degree;
    int next;
    int adr = *p->coeffs;
    int *arr = p->coeffs;
    int res = arr[d];
    for(int i=0; i<=d; i++){
      adr+=(d-i);
      next = arr[adr];
      adr-=(d-i);
      res = res*x+next;
    }
    return res;
  }


  //constructor : .txt
  poly_t *poly_alloc_d(){
    //needs to be finished
  }
```

Number Two: main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "poly.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  if(argc<3){
    fprintf(stderr, "syntax: %s x coeffs...", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  poly_t *p = poly_alloc(argc-3);

  for(int i = 2; i<argc; i++){
    int coeff = atoi (argv[i]);
    poly_set_coeff(p, i-2, coeff);
  }
  return 0;//for debugging 


  int x=atoi(argv[1]);
  int y=poly_eval(p,x);
  poly_free(p);
  printf("%d\n", y);

  return 0;

}
```

And at last my header file:
poly.h

```
#ifndef POLY_H 
#define POLY_H

/* unvollständiger Verbund */ 
typedef struct poly_t poly_t;
poly_t *poly_alloc(unsigned degree);
void poly_free(poly_t *p);
void poly_set_coeff(poly_t *p, unsigned deg, int coeff);
int poly_eval(poly_t const *p, int x);

#endif /* POLY_H */
```

I appreciate every help. I hope you can help me sort this out and please be patient with me a newbie to C...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? They are often very useful for finding the location of a runtime error, such as a segmentation fault.

Comment: Adding to *Frxstrem*'s comment: Read here might help: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: But, what are you exactly trying to achieve here: `poly_t *p = poly_alloc(argc-3);`? You pass `3-3` typically, at least when following the usage.

Comment: According to `gdb`, the segmentation faults occur at line 31 in poly.c: `p->coeffs[deg] = coeff;`

Comment: `printf("%d",*p->coeffs);` won't work. For one thing it should be `printf("%d",p->coeffs[0]);` and for another, you can't print a whole array in a single statement anyway.

Comment: `poly_alloc` never return value.

Comment: @Frxstrem I would guess that is because `p->coeffs` has no memory allocated for the array and even if it had, the previous line `p->coeffs += deg;` wrecks any chance of freeing the memory later..

Comment: @alk argc - 3 makes sense because it stands for the degree of the function: I can type. i.e. ./main 2 2 1 3 5 (./main x coeff,coeff, ...) and it should calculate 5*2^0+ 3*2^1 +1* 2^2 + 2* 2^3 . These are 6 arguments and the degree of the function is 3, which is correct.It should make space for the structs and the arrays....

Comment: @Weahter Vane not sure but am I not only printing one element per turn; the change, which u suggested did not change anything :( still thanks for the help

I am still not sure on how to fix this and I tried debugging it by inserting useful printf s in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not allocated or freed memory correctly, and the function didn't even return the pointer! I think you were trying to allocate one block of memory for the struct *and* the array it contains, but the struct does not contain an array: only a *pointer* to an array. You have to allocate them separately:

```
typedef struct { 
    unsigned degree;
    int *coeffs; 
    } poly_t; 

//constructor: heap
poly_t *poly_alloc(unsigned degree){

    poly_t *heap_p;
    heap_p = malloc(sizeof(*heap_p));
    if (heap_p == NULL)
        exit (1);           // allocation error

    heap_p->coeffs = malloc(degree * sizeof(int));
    if (heap_p->coeffs == NULL)
        exit (1);           // allocation error
    return heap_p;
}

//free heap
void poly_free(poly_t *p){
    free(p->coeffs);
    free(p);
}
```

There are other mistakes too, for example

```
p->coeffs += deg;
```

You mustn't play with the allocated memory pointer, you already did it correctly like this

```
p->coeffs[deg] = coeff;
```

although you can use an intermediate pointer if you want:

```
int *ptr = p->coeffs + deg;
*ptr = coeff;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! What you stated really helped me fix my code, I tested it and it works until it would free the allocated memory but then I get another error, free() invalid size(fast), which occurs, if what I googled is true, when i write over the array, which I created and reach a point out of bounds. Do you have any idea where that might be in my code? EDIT: I found it: I have to change the following line: heap_p->coeffs = malloc((degree+1)*sizeof(int)); because if i have a degree of 3, I need space for 4 coeffs a1*x^3 + a2*x^2 + a3*x^1 + a4*x^0